# Do you use the structure 'make + it + adjective + gerund'?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know both A) and B) are okay. But how about C)? That is, can I replace ‘to communicate’ with ‘communicating’ in the following sentence?

> A) Aphasia is a language disorder that makes it **very difficult to communicate**.
>   B) Aphasia is a language disorder that makes it **very difficult communicating**.
>   C) Aphasia is a language disorder that makes **communicating very difficult**.

Answer (score 1):

a) Aphasia is a language disorder that makes it very difficult to communicate. [preferred]
b) Aphasia is a language disorder that makes it very difficult communicating [with you]. [informal, very used]
c) Aphasia is a language disorder that makes communicating very difficult. [preferred]

These are all grammatical and fine.

to make it ADJ to verb
to make it ADJ + noun gerund [more here: with you, for example]
to make [noun gerund] + ADJ

make generally follows this pattern:

make x [adjective].

The dummy it makes it possible to use a to + verb and/or clause or a gerund noun.

The guitar makes it fun to play with you.
The guitar makes it fun playing with you.
The guitar makes playing with you fun.

But notice: the third one is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

All three would be perfectly understandable & equivalent in everyday usage. I'm trying - and struggling - to find a rule that dictates which, if any, are grammatically preferred.

Comment: I have to disagree a bit - as a US English speaker, I find B extremely clunky at best, although it's understandable.  I think it's awkward because the normal structure is "X makes Y Z" but in version B, Y = *it*, and then we have two things afterwards, not just one.

Comment: Fair point, and in hindsight I'd be inclined to agree it's probably the least appealing of the three.

Comment: @Stangdon B is not pragmatically clunky in a conversation. "Distance makes it very difficult communicating [with you]", for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficult%20to%20communicate%2Cdifficult%20communicating%2Ccommunicating%20difficult%2Ccommunication%20difficult&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficult%20to%20communicate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifficult%20communicating%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommunicating%20difficult%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommunication%20difficult%3B%2Cc0) shows that 'difficult to communicate' and 'communication difficult' (as in 'Aphasia makes communication difficult') are much more commonly used than 'communicating difficult' and 'difficult communicating', so on those figures alone, your sentence A) is the best choice.